# "Anti-aliasing" (smoothness of curve) in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a way to increase the smoothness of a curve created by TikZ? I think, it's a problem with my TeX distribution (TeX Live on Manjaro). Compare it with the output below, which I created with gnuplot manually.

First plot (worse plot):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip(-4,-4) rectangle (1,4);

\draw plot[ raw gnuplot, smooth] function{
    f(x,y) = x**3-4*x+1-y**2;
    set isosamples 1000;
    set cont base;
    set cntrparam levels incre 0,0.1,0;
    set view map;      %for gnuplot manually
    unset surface;
    splot f(x,y);
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The upper and the lower section of the arc are quite edged.

To see the output, run the code with the option `-shell-escape`.

How many lines does your `.pgf-plot.table` output file consist of? Mine consists of 1509 lines.

[image]

Second plot (better plot):

Use `\draw plot file{***}` instead while `***` stands for the file name of the table created by gnuplot manually (1612 lines). 
But I don't know anymore how I managed to get this table file. Is there a difference between `cont` and `contour` or `incre` or `increment`? I tested `cont` and `cont base` or `levels discrete 0` all over the place, but don't know the right commands anymore, either the right order.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64908/discussion-on-question-by-thrash-anti-aliasing-smoothness-of-curve-in-tikz).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution by adding the line `set samples 1000;` to the plot command.

```
\draw plot[ raw gnuplot, smooth] function{
    f(x,y) = x**3-4*x+1-y**2;
    set isosamples 1000;
    set samples 1000;    % or 500 is still sufficient
    set cont base;
    set cntrparam levels incre 0,0.1,0;
    set view map;      % for gnuplot manually
    unset surface;
    splot f(x,y);
};
```

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/179mst/plotting_elliptic_curves_in_gnuplot/c83hgkw/